# jQuery UI - append a class, make it draggable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

**Hello!**

I just started with jQuery UI, so I'm already stuck with something...

I'm trying to make a web program which allows the user to make a floor plan. It has a drag & drop function.

---

It has a menu with several items which can be dragged around. The problem is, when it's dragged around, the item in the menu disappears (because it's dragged around). So I tried to fix that using this code:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.notActive').draggable({ //.notActive is an item in the menu
    stop: function(){
        $(this).removeClass('notActive'); 
        $(this).addClass('active'); //make it an active item
        $('#menu').append($('<div class="item notActive">Furniture</div>'));
        //this creates a new item in the menu
    }
});
```

Each `item` has the class `.notActive` because it's not dragged. When it's being dragged by the user it removes that class and receives the class `.active`. So when it's dragged it creates a new element inside `#menu` with the class `.notActive`. The problem is, that the new created (appended(?)) item in the menu is not `.draggable()`, even though it has the class `.notActive`.

Why is this? How can I create a new instance that IS `.draggable()`?

Apologies for any grammar mistakes, I'm Dutch.

**EDIT**

Here's the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8tpy7x3e/

Comment: Would you be able to create [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) that replicates the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not explicitly calling `draggable` on the new item that's added to the menu.

Something like this would work:

```
$('.notActive').draggable({ //.notActive is an item in the menu
  stop: function(){
    $(this).removeClass('notActive'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); //make it an active item
    //Create a new object
    var newItem = $('<div class="item notActive">Furniture</div>');
    //Make the new item "draggable" and add it to the menu
    newItem.draggable();
    $('#menu').append(newItem);
    //this creates a new item in the menu
  }
});
```

[Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/3sqyszta/1/)